# adding drop downs in td for a table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i am new to jquery. My requirement is to show dropdown for each td cell in table. while for first click on td cell i am able to meet the requirement, but while clicking the next td, dropdown is not populating. requesting your help. thanks in advance

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var currenttd=null;
$(document).ready(function(){
$("td").click(function(){


$("#dropdown-content").css({"display":"block"});

$(this).append($("#dropdown-content"));

currenttd=this;


});
});


$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").click(function(){

currenttd.innerHTML=$(this).text();


});
});

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div>
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">MS</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">Dhoni</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">sachin</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">tendulkar</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">28</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="dropdown-content" style="display:none;position:absolute;
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    min-width:50px;
    box-shadow:0px 8px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)">
    <a href="#" style="color:black;padding:12px 16px;text-decoration:none;display:block">Link1</a>
    <a href="#" style="color:black;padding:12px 16px;text-decoration:none;display:block">Link2</a>
    <a href="#" style="color:black;padding:12px 16px;text-decoration:none;display:block">Link7</a>
    <a href="#" style="color:black;padding:12px 16px;text-decoration:none;display:block">Link4</a>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: The dropdown seems to be popping up for me on any `<td>` click above. Is it not for you? Also, do you want the same links in each dropdown?

Comment: @blubberbo dropdown is poping up is didn't select any value from it. if i select a value from drop down, for rest of the td, drop down is not poping up. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for the most part but the issue is that you append the html inside the `td` tag but on the `click` of `a`, you remove it by setting the `innerHTML` as the selected text. To get around this, you need to `clone()` the dropdown and use it to append to a local object. Other thing you need to do is to check for the `target` event.

```
var currenttd=null;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("td").click(function(e){
      if(e.target.tagName != "A")
      {
        var dropDownContent = $("#dropdown-content").clone();
        $(dropDownContent).css({"display":"block"});
        $(this).append($(dropDownContent));
        currenttd=this;   
        $("a").click(function(){
         $(currenttd).html($(this).text());
         $(dropDownContent).hide();
      });  
      }
    });   
});
```

Working here : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/co5wkj61/1/

Comment: Thanks for the code @DinoMyte. but when i click on td and without selecting the value and proceed to next td on click on it,  dropdown of pervious td is not closing. could you please tell me why we need to check the target event.

Comment: Hi @DinoMyte,
i have added below snippet, it working.since td cells are editable,if i make td as empty value,then also dropdown still visible


if(null!=currenttd){
  if(undefined!=currenttd.querySelectorAll("#dropdown-content")[0]){
  
currenttd.querySelectorAll("#dropdown-content")[0].style.display= "none";
    }
  }